# Get specific words from text file and make a table

Tags: python, regex, list, dictionary, cron

I have a crontab file as my input file. I would like to make another file with users and the scripts run by each of them and also the host on which it is being run.

**My Input File:**

List of users having Cron Job on host xyz.com

1  mark

2  adams

3  elaineli

4  vincent

5  chloe

Listing cron job of mark

---

*/5 * * * *  /home/mark.pl

*/120 * * * * /home/mark.sh

Listing cron job of adams

---

*/5 * * * *  /home/adams.sh

Listing cron job of elaineli

---

MAILTO=elaineli@micron.com

#*/10 * * * * /home/elaineli/test.py

Listing cron job of chloe

---

7 */6 * * * ~/test1.py
17 */6 * * * ~/ktest2.py

**Expected Output:**

Host                      User              ScriptBeingRun

xyz.com     mark        mark.pl

xyz.com     mark        mark.sh

xyz.com     adams       adams.sh

xyz.com     elaineli    test.py (should not come as it is disabled)

xyz.com     chloe       test1.py

xyz.com     chloe       ktest2.py

**My code:**

```
import sys
import re

Lines = [Line.strip() for Line in open ('/home/dineshb/2016/jan/ETLJobReport/tslhdppetl01/input1.txt','r').readlines()]

for EachLine in Lines:
    if re.match(r'Listing', EachLine):
        User = EachLine
        print User

    if re.match(r'\*',EachLine):
        Jobs = re.findall(r'\/(.+?)\.sh',EachLine)
        print Jobs
```

I dont know how to proceed. I am able to get the words that require, just not sure how to make it into the expected output. Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First you need to save the data you find, not just print them. Second you need to keep track of which user you are currently reading jobs for when reading the job parts. You can fx store username in a string, then read on till you find a new user (or end of file), storing each job run in a list. Then when you find new user, you print a line with server + username + list[i] to print the previous users jobs. (hope that makes sense)

Comment: yeah, i do get the logic of how it is being done... just that i am not sure on the coding part as i am just trying to learn python